# Intermittent 405 Status response from ajax delete request

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

So I've got these cards, a user can click the delete button to remove a card. The card has an ID which deletes the card ID or `community_id` and `user_id` from the table. When the clicks the delete button, it sends an ajax `delete` request to the resource controller (delete method) which does delete the row from the database... sometimes.

It's very strange, sometimes it works, other times it returns a `405` (Method Not Allowed Exception).

Here's the code:

View:

```
            @foreach($communities as $community)
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card communityCard">
                        <div class="loadingCard" loading>
                            <i class="loadingSpinner fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="commandPanel">
                            <div class="commandPanelInterior">
                                @if($community->banned == 1)
                                    @php($community->description = "This community has been removed for violating our terms of service.")
                                @else
                                    <form class="form" action="/cad" method="GET">
                                        @csrf

                                        <input name="community_id" type="hidden" value="{{$community->id}}">

                                        <button type="submit" class="sideMenuButton hvr-grow btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-door-open"></i></button>
                                    </form>
                                @endif

                                @if($community->owner_id != Auth::user()->id)
                                    <button id="deleteCommunity{{$community->id}}" value="{{$community->id}}" type="submit" class="deleteCommunityButton sideMenuButton hvr-grow btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-header">
                            <img class="communityIcon" src="/images/communityIcons/{{$community->icon_path}}">
                            <span class="communityName">{{$community->name}}</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <span class="communityDescription">{{$community->description}}</span>
                        </div>

                        @if($community->banned == 0)
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <span class="badge badge-light"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> {{$community->user_count}}</span>

                                @php($communityBadges = $community->badge_types)

                                @foreach($communityBadges as $badgeType)
                                    <span class="badge badge-primary" title="{{$badgeType->name}}">{!!$badgeType->badge_icon!!}</span>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

Javascript:

```
        // Remove User From Community Ajax

        $('.deleteCommunityButton').click(function(event){
            var clickedBtn = "#" + (event.target.id);
            var community_id = $(event.target).val();

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: '/communitymembers/'+community_id,
                data: {
                    "id": community_id,
                    "_method": 'DELETE'
                },

                success: function(response) {
                    $(clickedBtn).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
                }
            });
        });
```

Controller:

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $memberList = CommunityMemberList::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('community_id', $id)->first();

        $memberList->delete();

        return redirect('/home')->with('message', 'The community has been successfully removed from your account');;
    }
```

Web.php File:

`Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');`

Error (From Console):

`"message": "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.",`

Thanks :)

Comment: Can try again after you make the type of ajax request in the delete community button handler a delete? Make it type:"DELETE"?

Comment: Already done that, does the same thing. 405.